# How to import nested JSON to SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a nested JSON variable(I use shortened version here) which I wanna insert into table. I am able to take not nested columns and values however struggling with nested part. What I want is retrieving 2 rows: one for sessionID = 20 and other one for 30 with sub columns. I am using SQL Server 2017.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'{
"List":
[
    {
    "ID": 13,
    "Date": "2015-12-07",
    "SessionID": {
      "20": {
        "discount": "no",
        "price": 15.99
            },
      "30": {
       "discount": "yes",
        "price": 12.99
            }
        }
    }
]
}'  



SELECT *  
FROM OPENJSON(@json, N'lax $.List')
WITH (ID int '$.ID' 
     ,[Date] date '$.Date'
     ,SessionID nvarchar(max) N'lax $.SessionID' AS JSON
     )
```

I would like retrieve data as below. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: I would like retrieve query like this]

Comment: One option is using cross apply. e.g. adding `cross apply openjson(sessionid) as s cross apply openjson(s.value) with (discount nvarchar(3) '$.discount', price money '$.price') as v` (where sessionid would be s.key)

Comment: I hope there will be a day when questions containing proper sample data, shows effort and expected results will be so common they will not deserve an upvote - but it is not this day.

Comment: The problem here is that your json is ill formatted - a proper json should contain pairs of key:value, that might be nested (meaning that the value will also contain json data). However, in your case - you have the session ids (20 and 30) as keys instead of as values - making it much harder to extract them from the json using the standard `openjson` function. If you can change the source json to include the 20 and 30 as values, it would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Zohard Peled told you, the internal structure of your JSON is something to improve. In general it is not a good idea to place data as element name. It was better to use something like `"SessionID":"20"`, while your JSON comes up with the `"20"` as name of the following object.

Nevertheless this can be done, using the `key` column of `OPENJSON`:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json =  
N'{
"List":
[
    {
    "ID": 13,
    "Date": "2015-12-07",
    "SessionID": {
      "20": {
        "discount": "no",
        "price": 15.99
            },
      "30": {
       "discount": "yes",
        "price": 12.99
            }
        }
    }
]
}'
```

--The query will travers down your structure step-by-step:

```
SELECT B.ID
      ,B.[Date]

      ,C.[key] AS SessionID --here's the magic...

      ,JSON_VALUE(C.[value],'$.discount') AS discount
      ,JSON_VALUE(C.[value],'$.price') AS price
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(List NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A --getting "List" as JSON
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.List)
WITH(ID INT
    ,[Date] DATE
    ,SessionID NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) B --getting "ID" and "Date" and "SessionID as JSON
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(B.SessionID) C; --get the objects within the array, but nameless...
```

The result:

```
ID  Date    SessionID   discount    price
13  2015-12-07  20      no          15.99
13  2015-12-07  30      yes         12.99
```